# How to combine two data sets into one and plotting one graph with both data sets in R Studio

Tags: r, graph

Currently I have combined the Apple stock market and the Samsung stock market from 2014- 2018. I have combined the Date,Open,High, low and Close using cbind and changed the names so it says Apple/ Samsung.

My problem is with the graph, Now my dataset is combined in columns so I feel like this might be part of the problem, but none the less I would prefer to keep it like that. I would love a graph that would have both of the open figures on it over the years.

If I just use **plot(Total$OpenApple, Total$OpenSam)** the plot is a huge block compared to the line graph I would like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without any example data its difficult to understand your problem fully. However, I would try using the `ggplot2` package and `dplyr` package. Then you can change your data so that OpenApple and OpenSam are both part of the same column, and then use a function from `ggplot2` to change the colors of your lines based on what group they are a part of.